# How to check in which datetime period / time block a datetime belongs to?

Tags: pandas, datetime

I am having a stream of timestamped data parsed and put into a `DataFrame`. The timestamps are ordered and incremental. They represent events happening.

I want to `resample` the data using `pandas.DataFrame.resample` for an arbitrary window size `x`. I also want to have a flag/check to see if the last event that has arrived does not belong to the current window but has moved to the next window of size `x`.

```
                    Timespans
15:00         16:00           17:00           18:00
|-------A-------|-------B-------|-------C-------|
       event_a^   ^event_b
```

How to check that `event_b.time` does not belong in the same time span as `event_b.time`.

`event_a.time` is a `pandas.Timestamp` object

Answer (score 0):

I thought of using the `pd.Period` class and just do

```
pd.Period(event_a.time, freq=x) == pd.Period(event_b.time, freq=x)
```

which works as intended.

Unfortunately, I do not see anyway for `pd.Period` to accept offsets in case I want a period to start from `16:12` and end at `17:12`

---

Update: `pd.Period` cannot take into account frequencies less than `1H`. Attempting to do

```
pd.Period(pd.to_datetime('20170101 10:32'), '30min')
Out[12]: Period('2017-01-01 10:32', '30T') # 10:32 instead of 11:00
```

I submitted [a ticket to pandas github repo](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17666) about it and will try to update if anything comes out of it. In the meantime I found a way to do the rounding by using `pandas.Timestamp.floor` and `pandas.Timestamp.ceil`

```
pd.to_datetime('20170101 10:32:30').floor('30min')
Out[1]: Timestamp('2017-01-01 10:30:00')
pd.to_datetime('20170101 10:32:30').ceil('30min')
Out[2]: Timestamp('2017-01-01 11:00:00')
```